# Change scroll behavoiur of a listview

Tags: android, list, listview, scroll, scrollbar

I have an android listview, that gets new data every second. Now I would like to scroll through this list, but every time new data is arriving, the view moves to the first element of this list. Is it possible to change the behaviour in the way that the view does not move to the first element when new data arrives?

Every time I get new data, I do the following:

```
if(arg1.getStringExtra("DATA")!=null){
                text = arg1.getStringExtra("DATA").split("\n");
                //Erstellt aus den Daten des Traceservices eine Liste bestehend aus Ergebnissen
                //Result: <(technName,(min,max,invald,color,numeric),aktuellerWert>
                List<Results> results = new ArrayList<Results>();
                if(text.length>0){
                    for(String x:text){
                        Results r = new Results();
                        String []res =x.split("&&&");
                        Values v = dataDictionary.get(res[0]);
                        r.name=res[0];
                        r.setV(v);
                        if(res.length>1){
                            r.setCurrentValues(res[1]);
                        }
                        results.add(r);
                    }
                    ResultAdapter adapter = new ResultAdapter(getApplicationContext(), results);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }
```

The ResultAdapter looks like this:

```
public class ResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<Results> resultList;

public ResultAdapter(Context context, List<Results> resultList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.resultList = resultList;
}

public int getCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return resultList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Results r = resultList.get(position);
    return new ResultAdapterView(this.context, r);
}
```

}

Not sure if you need it, but the ResultAdapterView was implemented this way:

```
class ResultAdapterView extends LinearLayout {

public ResultAdapterView(Context context, Results r) {
    super(context);
    this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams resParams;
    TextView resName = new TextView(context);
    resParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(170, 25);
    resParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
    resName.setPadding(0, 3, 0, 0);
    resName.setText(r.v.getFriendlyName());
    resName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    addView(resName, resParams);

    if(r.v!=null){
        if (!r.v.isNumeric()) {

            TextView currVal = new TextView(context);
            currVal.setText(r.currentValue);
            currVal.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            addView(currVal, resParams);

        } else {
            ResultView rv = new ResultView(context, r);
            addView(rv, resParams);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for your help.

Greetings

Christine

Comment: Please show the code adding data to your adapter.

Comment: Could you post the code that insert new data into the adapter? Do you insert it, or just refresh the whole adapter?

Comment: found it out: instead of instanciating a new ResultAdapter every time, I call the method adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

The list jumps to the beginning because you call ".setAdapter(...)" when the new data arrives. What you need to do is extends you adapter as such:

```
public class ResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<Results> resultList;

public ResultAdapter(Context context, List<Results> resultList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.resultList = resultList;
}

public int getCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return resultList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Results r = resultList.get(position);
    return new ResultAdapterView(this.context, r);
}

public void setNewData(List<Results> newResults){   
..Add the new data to the current ones or switch, whatever ...
notifyDatasetChanged();
}
}
```

Whenever the new data arrives, just call the .setNewData() on your adapter, instead of creating a whole new adapter and setting it up with the list. Note the notifyDatasetChanged() call, you must call that in these cases.